# Как сравнить правильно два словаря, чтобы возвращаемые данные были в одном списке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dict

Есть два словаря, в которых хранится id товара (ключ) и его наименование (значение). Вот пример:

```
dict_old = {
    'R1': 'клавиатура',
    'R2': 'компьютерная мышь',
    'R3': 'наушники',
    'R4': 'пульт',
    'R5': 'телевизор',
    'R6': 'микрофон',
}

dict_new = {
    'L2': 'пылесос',
    'R6': 'микрофон',
    'R3': 'наушники',
    'R5': 'телевизор',
    'L1': 'телефон',
    'L3': 'приставка',
}
```

Нужно, чтобы происходило сравнение этих двух словарей по ключу. То есть, как я это представляю: 1 словарь - это старый словарь, а 2 словарь - это новый словарь. И если во 2 словаре есть новый ключ (id), которого нет в 1 словаре, то надо чтобы в консоль выводилось значение этих ключей (наименование) в списке.

Пример:

```
['пылесос', 'телефон', 'приставка']
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать

Comment: привели бы код например, что не получается. А так вопрос хороший

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ещё можно через вычитание множеств ключей:

```
print([dict_new[x] for x in set(dict_new) - set(dict_old)])
# ['пылесос', 'телефон', 'приставка']
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну есть способ втупую. Проходим по второму словарю и чекам, есть ли ключ в первом. Я и принчу, по можно аппендить в список и получить, то что вам нужно.

```
for k in dict_new:
  if k in dict_old:
       print(dict_new[k])
```

Answer (score 2):

ну судя по всему вам нужно просто пройтись по значениям:

```
res = [x for x in dict_new.values() if x not in dict_old.values()]
```

res:

```
['пылесос', 'телефон', 'приставка']
```